# How to correctly perform an interval regression

Tags: r, modeling

I have some intervaled data (height above ground in intervals of 2 meters) and I would like to use some categorical descriptors to fit a model.

I am using R package `survival`.

1) My response data is skewed (most values are located in the first interval: 0-2 meters). Should I perform any transformation or choose a distribution other than gaussian?

2) How do I run a residual analysis for this kind of model?

Thank you in advance.